# Stop receiving messages after receiving a particular message from observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Observable emits values like 1,1,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,.. 4...,5,6..

How could I stop receiving messages after receiving a particular element 4, Observable should stop consuming next element onwards.

Thanks in advance for help.

order of the messages are not same.

Comment: TakeWhile or takeUntil might be an interesting operator for this.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [takeWhile](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takewhile).

`TakeWhile` makes sure, once `4` value is emitted then it will not receive other emitted value(s).

```
of(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6)
.pipe(
      takeWhile(x=> x !== 4)
 ).subscribe(r => console.log('result', r));
```

Comment: order is not the same, it's just an example I gave. After receiving 4, next messages should not be consumed.

Comment: I just updated the answer. Now order doesn't matter. Once emitted 4, it will not emit further numbers.